# getting two different date months

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I'm a newbie trying to learn JavaScript through a video course on Lynda.com 
The instructor started with the `alert()` code to make what we wrote show up in an alert box. And then he showed about writing code to come back with today's date in an alert box:

```
var date = new Date();
alert("Today's date is " + date);
```

> I am including this to show that the date variable was set for the current date.

Next thing was making what we wrote appear on the actual web page section, at the top of the open document.

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>The date today is " + date + "<h1>"
```

And it came back with the same date, `June 15` only, this time in the web page itself.

This next part is where I got a different month, despite putting in exactly what I was supposed to. To make it more readable, we're told about the get function to grab specific pieces of information.

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>The date today is " + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + "</h1>"
```

and it comes back with:

> **The date today is 5/15/2018**

I can't figure out why it's telling me it's May 15, 2018 while earlier the date was correct. I can't figure out where my code is wrong. Any help that can be given would be appreciated.

Comment: month in dates is zero based - i.e. January is 0, not 1 - as documented in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

Comment: Months are 0 based when you `date.getMonth()` so January is month 0 and June is month 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript `getMonth()` method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time. That means, January is 0, February is 1, and so on. So, current month (June) returned 5 in your output.

To get the desired output in your code, correct it like below:

```js
var date = new Date();
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>The date today is " +  (parseInt(date.getMonth(), 10) + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + "</h1>";
```

Comment: I don't know, maybe, he somehow forgot to mention this. And how can you tell that his output was correct, maybe his output was also one months earlier. You never know when he recorded his video :-p

Comment: Can you share the link please (I wanna have a look at it), obviously if the course is free.

Comment: I'm taking the course through my local library website, so it's free. But if you take it through Lynda.com directly, it's not. If you're lucky, your library offers access to websites like Lynda.com and Microsoft Certification Training courses (I've taken a Excel 2013 Essentials course through the library link, and plan on taking more Microsoft  Certification training courses). Here's the link [link]https://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-tutorials/JavaScript-Essential-Training/574716-2.html[link]

Answer (score 1):

This is intended as the returned month is zero-based so June is indeed month 5.

From the `date.getMonth()` docs on MDN:

> The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: As I said, I'm new to this, and don't quite understand your answer. If the code was wrong, why does the instructor in the video use it and get the correct answer (for the date that he made the video)? I put in the exact same thing as he did